# Does he like them or not? Another Grandpa Mystery

Tags: riddle, no-computers

Now I know very well the weird likes and dislikes of Grandpa.

Yesterday he tells me:

> "Son
>
> I like Queen but not the Queen
>
> I liked the King but not the King
>
> I like Monarch but not Monarchs
>
> I like Prince but not the Prince"

Wha does he like and dislike? Why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

He likes

> Musical Royalty, but not Actual Royalty

I like Queen but not the Queen

> The band Queen, but not a royal Queen

I liked the King but not the King

> Elvis Presley, but not a royal King

I like Monarch but not Monarchs

> The band Monarch, but not royal Monarchs

I like Prince but not the Prince

> The singer Prince, but not a royal Prince

Comment: this was my first thought^^